# How can i calculate network load of this camera?

Tags: compression

It's part of an assignment that i am trying to solve
Determine the network load from a security camera given the
following camera specs:

a. Resolution: 1200x800
b. Color: 8-bit color gamut
c. Speed: 30 frames pr. second.
d. Compression: 3/1000

How would you go about it? Is it a matter of calculating total bits pr frame?

Comment: It's not usual to see compression specified in that manner, maybe you should go back to the source and ask them what it means.  Also you'll need to divide by 8 to convert bits to bytes.

Comment: Well i'm trying to do an assignment which says:
"Determine the network load from a cameras given the
following camera specs:
a. Resolution: 1200x800
b. Color: 8-bit color gamut
c. Speed: 30 frames pr. second.
d. Compression: 3/1000"

So in this context i thought "network load" would be = Total amounts of bits?
If not. How should i go about solving this question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information it is not so complicated to calculate:

1. To get the total number of pixels: `1200*800=960000`
2. Then its unclear about the bits depth if its total number of colours
   or per channel (RGB). I assume second (so 3 bytes): `960000*3=2880000`
3. For second we need to multiply by 30 (frames per second) 
   `86400000*30=86400000`
4. To get in consideration compression we multiply by 3 and delete to
   1000: `86400000*3/1000=259200` bytes per second
5. And `259200/1024=253.12` kilobytes per second